# Where is the assumption of right continuity used in the following proof?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Lemma:If $X$ be a right-continuous positive local martingale then , $X$ is a generalized super martingale
Proof:
$\forall s<t$

$$E[X_t\mid F_s]=E[\lim_{n\to\infty} X_{t \wedge\tau_n}\mid F_s] \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty }E[X_{t \wedge\tau_n}\mid F_s]= \liminf_{n\to \infty} X_{s\wedge\tau_n}=X_s$$

I fail to see where the assumption of right continuity being used.
It often happens that in proves of continuous time processes , I fail to see where the assumptions are being used unless explicitly mentioned in the text
Thank you 
EDIT: Its a positive martingale?

Comment: Note that I changed \text{^} to \wedge, and thus $t\text{^}\tau_n$ to $t\wedge\tau_n$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thank you I didn't know \wedge and was hoping someone would fix it.:)

Comment: I would say, you need left-continuity and not right-continuity.

Comment: @saz Saz my lecture notes explicitly say right continuity. But could you explain where is it being used in the proof?

Comment: @user3503589 Sorry, my mistake. I thought we needed it in order to ensure that $\liminf_n X_{s \wedge \tau_n}=X_s$, but that's not true since we can always pick $N=N(s,\omega)$ such that $s \wedge \tau_n = s$ for all $n \geq  N$.

Comment: @saz but this $\liminf_n X_{s \wedge \tau_n}= X_s$ holds only a.s right because $\tau_n \to \infty$ a.s

Comment: @user3503589 Yeah, but the equalities are all almost surely.

Comment: @saz Yes ofcourse, Thank you!